# Eliminating duplicate records in data cleansing

Tags: maintenance

I have a database full of records of people with simple information like first name, last name, email, location, ... . I need to eliminate the duplicate records. As I've search the process is called "duplicate elimination in Data Cleansing". Does anyone know a good open source tool to do that?

Comment: What RDBMS ? Is it using TSQL or PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

Using T-SQL & PL/SQL, you can use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY) to find and delete duplicate records in a Table.

Refer to some best examples [Removing Duplicates from a Table in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/) 
and [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) as well as [Oracle 'Partition By' and 'Row_Number' keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477085/oracle-partition-by-and-row-number-keyword)

Comment: The thing is my duplicate records are not exactly the same. two records may differ in one field or more.

Comment: @AliBZ In that case, I would recommend you highlighting the duplicate records (selecting) and then asking your Business owners to decide it. If you refer to the links that I have mentioned, then it has all scenarios of finding duplicate records. Also, if the same record differs in one or more field then how is it a Duplicate ? Post create table statement with some data and your expected results to help you better

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL you can do so with a "simple" SQL statement which may apply to other SQL databases with little or no tweaks:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates

Note that it deletes all entries that have a higher ID, better to know that...

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT id,
         row_number() over (partition BY column1, column2, column3 ORDER BY id) AS rnum
         FROM tablename) t
  WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool we use to remove duplicate records in our database (Access) is [WinPure Clean & Match](http://www.winpure.com/cleanmatch.html), I think also they do an API for fuzzy matching.